# Using PHP as a CSS file?

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, include

How would I go about using PHP as a CSS file. I have just included it as a normal css file, but it fails to work in Google Chrome.

Comment: please post the source of that php file

Comment: Do you set the content type header in the PHP file?

Comment: Do you want do use a css content saved as php file ? Is that what I undestood? Why such a thing?

Comment: @B4NZ41 sometimes people want dynamic CSS files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to tell the browser that it is a CSS-file and not a HTML-file, write the following before any output:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

See:
http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor/

Answer (score 8):

Try adding

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

in first line of your stylesheet.php